# typeof(data.frame) shows "list" in R

Tags: r, attributes

Can someone clarify why **typeof (data.frame)** shows **list** in R?  In contrast, class gives expected type. E.g., demonstrate that using the built-in data.frame mtcars.

```
> typeof(mtcars)
[1] "list"
> class(mtcars)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Any hints on how to use typeof versus class?

Answer (score 17):

data.frame and data.table are both collections (lists) of items (vectors, if you will), each item of the same length (ie each column is an item in the list, internally to R anyway). This is why unlike in a matrix, columns can have different classes.

Cheers.

Comment: "its not you, it's R"

Comment: I've said "wtf R" so many times in the past week, but this was elucidating, thank you. I can add this to my frustration over needing to check whether an object is an S3, S4, or RC object in order to examine its methods.